# sending email with GAE copies sender -- how to stop?

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I'm creating an app with GAE to allow people to vote in elections and this involves sending an email to each voter.  I do this in a loop:

```
mail.send_mail(sender = manager.email(),
               to = email,
               subject = election.title,
               body = body)
```

where manager is the signed-in user.

This appears to BCC the manager on all emails, but I don't want that to happen.  Is there a way to send the email only to the intended recipient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - App Engine automatically BCCs the sender. If you don't want to receive them, you could use one of your app's incoming email addresses as the sender address.

Answer (score 2):

There is an Issue logged for this problem here:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2059

Please "star" it if you want Google to fix it.