# google app engine sending a copy of email to my inbox

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sending email with GAE copies sender — how to stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137219/sending-email-with-gae-copies-sender-how-to-stop)

Below is a code to send emails from google app engine in Python. I made a list (pythons) of email-ids to whom I desire to send email to and ran a loop, each time reassigning message.to and executing message.send().

Code below, when run on Google App Engine, sends a copy of email to the sender (AUTH_USER1@gmail.com) of the email (along with the email sent to the desired email-id). What could be possible reason for this?

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import users

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()

    if user and user.nickname()=="AUTH_USER1":
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))



    message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="Auth User1 <AUTH_USER1@gmail.com>",
    subject="Testing Google App Engine")

    message.html = """

hi, how have you been
"""
    list = ['A@gmail.com','B@hotmail.com', 'C@yahoo.com']
    for i in range(0,len(list)):
        message.to = list[i]
        message.send()


application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                 [('/', MainPage)],
                                 debug=True)
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @Chris: I'm new to SO. Please let me know if I need to delete this question (as per SO guidelines).

Comment: Don't worry about doing anything, people will flag things and have them cleaned up as we go. Try to use the search for various terms before posting though as it can get tiresome for others answering similar questions. Enjoy your stay ;)

Comment: A way to avoid it is to send mails as scheduled cron jobs. A copy is not sent to the sender in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. You cannot send email from a user in App Engine without the user getting a copy.