# Sending Emails with Python, Google AppEngine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sending email with GAE copies sender — how to stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137219/sending-email-with-gae-copies-sender-how-to-stop)

I'm using Python with Google's App Engine and I am working on sending emails to users.

I have it so users can respond to posts by emailing them. However, it also, by default, sends a copy of the email to the user. Is it possible to disable this?

This is the code I have:

```
mail.send_mail( 
   user.email(), # from
   greeting.author.email(), # to 
   'MSUchat: %s is %s - %s' % (user, response.inquiry, greeting.title), # subj
   'You received a response to your posting.\r\n\r\n%s wrote:\r\n\r\n"%s"' % (user, response.content), # body 
)
```

I only want this email to be sent to the person they are responding to, not have it sent to themselves as well.

Comment: Please format your code properly.  Please **Edit** your question and read the markup guidelines on the edit page.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wooble's duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137219/sending-email-with-gae-copies-sender-how-to-stop/5137547#5137547):

> You can't - App Engine automatically BCCs the sender. If you don't want to receive them, you could use one of your app's incoming email addresses as the sender address.

Comment: any other better way to get them to stop copying the email to the sender?  I'm doing a "buy and sell" service, so users contact each other through email, is their a setting I can change possibly?